# BigQuery query is trying to hit through a wrong account during execution

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

The query is trying to hit an another account when I am trying to execute the query by selecting it's own account.

```
ACTIVE  ACCOUNT
        <SERVICE_ACCOUNT_1>@<PROJECT_ID_1>.iam.gserviceaccount.com
*       <SERVICE_ACCOUNT_2>@<PROJECT_ID_2>.iam.gserviceaccount.com

To set the active account, run:
    $ gcloud config set account `ACCOUNT`
```

Now I am executing the query of the table of the selected account `<SERVICE_ACCOUNT_2>@<PROJECT_ID_2>.iam.gserviceaccount.com` but I will get the error of  Error processing job of the account `'<SERVICE_ACCOUNT_1>@<PROJECT_ID_1>.iam.gserviceaccount.com'` which is not selected above.

```
[hive@ip-172-42-50-253 gcs-service-account-key]$ bq query --format=csv --quiet 'select max(cast(uid as INT64)) from <PROJECT_ID_2>.<DATASET>.<TABLE>'

BigQuery error in query operation: Error processing job '<PROJECT_ID_1>:<JOB_ID>': Access Denied: Table
<PROJECT_ID_2>:<DATASET>.<TABLE>: User does not have permission to query table <PROJECT_ID_2>:<DATASET>.<TABLE>.
```

Why the query is getting permission error and why the query is trying to hit through an another account's table in the same database.

Comment: Where do you see the user which is used in this error trace?

Comment: I have a couple of doubts: Where are you running the command `` bq```? What process are you doing to activate the service account? [Was this?](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/authorizing#authorizing_with_a_service_account)

Comment: If you're in doubt, try `SELECT SESSION_USER()` to confirm what is current user.